# Is there a way to merge the commit history from an SVN repository to a Git branch?

Tags: git, version-control, git-svn, version-control-migration

We currently have several small semi-related SVN repos that are inactive as far as commits go. However, they occasionally need to be used and/or their commit history needs to be reviewed. We would like to move all of them into a single pre-existing Git repo as most of our work is done on Git these days...

In doing research, what I think I want to achieve is to have a Git subtree branch for each SVN repo which has all of the commit history. But, git-svn seems to only allow me to relate 1 SVN repo to 1 Git repo, so I would have to create a git repo for each project first, and then convert to a subtree in the final repo. (I think)

Is there a way to merge the history from an SVN repo directly onto a branch in my Git repository so that I can effectively skip the step of creating redundant Git repos?

Comment: git-svn, as per your tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the reason I was wanting to avoid extra repositories was that we are using GitHub to store our repositories and the extra repositories I would need to create would put us over the limit of our current plan.

As such, the trick, I found out, is to keep all of the repositories local. I knew this was a possibility, but wasn't sure how to reference the local repositories. It turns out it couldn't have been more easy! Here are the steps I went through:

For each SVN repository:

```
git svn clone http://svnhost.com/path/to/svn/repo
```

This will create a local Git repo with all of the history from SVN (even timestamps are preserved!!). Next, go to the repo you want to merge it in to. Create a branch, and pull in the code from:

```
git checkout -b newsvnbranch1
git pull path_to_newsvnbranch1_git_repo
```

Now, the remaining steps aren't part of the original question, but they were the end goal that I needed to accomplish - all the SVN repos and histories merged together, but in their own directories.

```
git mv trunk newname1
git checkout master
git merge newsvnbranch1
```

Completing those steps for each SVN repo essentially leaves your original Git repo with the following structure:

```
original
|-newname1  (containing the contents of the first SVN repo)
|-newname2  (containing the contents of the second SVN repo)
|-newname3  (and so on...)
```

And, `git log` will now show the history of each repo intertwined.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is easier in git.  I'd use a tool like [`git2svn`](https://github.com/etgryphon/git2svn) to import the Subversion repositories into git.

Once in git, you can setup a new repository with branches.  You could set up each branch to track one converted Subversion repository.  Once you've fetched the change sets, you can clear the remote tracking with [`git remote remove`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html).  That leaves you with a repository with the various changesets from Subversion on branches.